# Is this Patricia tree implementation wrong?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, binary-trees, trie

I'm reading the [chapter](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr09/cos226/handouts/Algs3Ch15.pdf) Radix Search of the book Algorithms (Robert Sedgwick).

I've made a simple implementation and something isn't behaving as expected.

In program `15.5` you can see that we start with an empty tree where the head is a null node. In figure `15.12` you can see that the null node is always the leftmost node. This is also described in the text:

> We use the convention that the leftmost link (the one correspond- ing to a key that is all 0 bits) does not point to any internal node

program `15.7` is the implementation of Patricia-trie insertion.

If you look at the code, there's never a chance for the head reference to change, let's say, to `A` as depicted in figure `15.12`.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Program 15.5* they state:

> The root of the trie is at `head.l` (the link `head.r` is
> unused).

`head.l` *does* get assigned.

Comment: Thanks @greybeard! so it's sort of like a dummy node I guess